# CURL input string url from FORM

Tags: php, html, curl, post, http-post

I am making a Form to insert a URL to my CURL program.

I will make Form like

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <label for="name">URLinput</label>
    <input type="text" name="urlinput" id="urlinput"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="Submit">
</form>
```

How can the code be updated to utilize the URL from the Form, like below?

```
<?php

$curl =curl_init();
$url = $_POST['urlinsert'];  //<----- like this 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

preg_match_all("!https://s[^\s]*?.bukalapak.com/img[^\s]*?.webp!", $result, $images);
$images = array_values(array_unique($images[0]));

print_r($images);

preg_match_all("!data-reduced-price=\"([^\s]*?)\"!", $result, $matches);
$price['harga'] = $matches[1];

print_r($price['harga']);

curl_close($curl);

php?>
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? You're referencing a different field name in your PHP script. You're trying to get a value from a field called `urlinsert` while your field is named `urlinput`.

Comment: What you wanted to do exactly? we do not understand whats the issue here,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the form is submitted, the *name* attribute of the text input will correspond to the value. If you were to inspect the values in [`$_POST`](http://php.net/$_POST) after the user has entered text in the text field and submitted the form, it should look like the following:

```
Array ( [urlinput] => s4.bukalapak.com/page.php [submit] => Submit )
```

For the url input, the *name* attribute is *urlinput*. So change this line:

```
$url = $_POST['urlinsert'];  //<----- like this
```

To:

```
$url = $_POST['urlinput'];  //<----- like this
```

See it demonstrated in [this phpfiddle example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xe3i-jz7p).

Comment: Thankyou @Sam, this working. But i Run this program in Laravel, i cant input that. that not working in Laravel. do you know this code in Laravel?

Comment: Sure- I advise you to [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include the relevant code (e.g. the Laravel controller or whatever code needs to access the POST data)

Comment: Ok Sam... youare The Best... hehehe

Comment: How Are you... hehe thans for helping me...
I've made a Question....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060808/how-to-use-this-php-method-code-in-laravel